# How to change the width or other css styles of a div in angular 5 by clicking a button?

Tags: dom, angular5, dom-manipulation

I am trying to load a full width navigation bar by clicking a menu icon. And i am using angular 5. I have tried googling about DOM manipulation in angular 5+ versions but its really confusing and complicated.
My question is about how can i change or manipulate these html elements using angular(typescript) like we used to do with plain javascript and JQuery.
My question is all about changing the width of a div but i want to know how can i work with other css styles and DOM manipulation techniques.

Here is my code

> home.component.html

```
 <section id="top">
  <div id="menu">
    <a id="toggle" (click)="openMenu()" >
      <i class="fa fa-bars menu-bar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="sidenav" class="overlay" ref="#sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <div class="overlay-content">
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Clients</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="heading">
    <div id="logo">Koa</div>
    <div id="tagline">next generation web framework for node.js</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

> home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

> styles.scss

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import "~bootswatch/dist/lux/_variables.scss";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
@import "~bootswatch/dist/lux/_bootswatch.scss";

body {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

//navbar
#menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 35px;
    right: 42px;
    z-index: 50;
}
#menu a#toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    background:transparent;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    z-index: 5;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    color: black;
}
//sidenav 
.overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}
//heading or showcase
#heading {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -150px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
#logo {
    font: 150px 'Italiana', sans-serif;
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
#tagline {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[ngClass]="{'scssClassName': condition}"` for conditioning class appendance on div like this:

`<div class="existingClassWithNormalWidth" [ngClass]="{'scssClassNameWithFullWidth': condition}">{{childTags}}</div>`.

You can also give different classes for different conditions on same tags like this: `[ngClass]="{'scssClassName': condition, 'scssClassName2': condition2, 'scssClassName3': anyBooleanVariable,}"`

You can set condition(or boolean) to be `true` by clicking button. Angular will automatically append the class to div itself.

You can also use `[ngStyle]` for only full width, but if you want to give extra style, you better make a class to SCSS and use `[ngClass]`.

Find official doc for class https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass
(If you want to append class)

Find official doc for style only https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle
(If only you want to make full width with ngStyle)